# Export SHP layer to JPG scale 1:1

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to export or print a SHP layer to JPG with JGW, while maintaining a 1:1 scale. The SHP layer is actually a CAD drawing, exported from AutoCAD Map3D. What is the recommended practice?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the problem?

Comment: a 1:1 scale map is going to be **very** big

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works